# Login and account system

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

So here I wanted to make a system that registered a person's account. It remembers the person's email, account, first and last names, by writing to a file. You can login to that account by typing the email and password according to that email and then you would get a hello message, saying your first and last name that you used to register your account with.

```
data_text = []
first_names = []
last_names = []
emails = []
passwords = []

def user_choice():
    print('Hello user, create an account or login to an existing one.')
    choice = input('Insert "1" if you wish to create an account or "2" if you wish to login: ')
    print('\r')
    if choice == '1':
        create_account()
        user_choice()
    else:
        login_account()
        user_choice()

def register_info():
    with open('Login_Data.txt', 'r') as login_data:
        global data_text, first_names, last_names, emails, passwords
        data_text = login_data.readlines()
        for i in data_text:
            data_text[data_text.index(i)] = i.strip()
        emails = (data_text[2::4])

def create_account():
    with open('Login_Data.txt', 'a') as login_data:
        first_name = input('First name: ')
        last_name = input('Last name: ')
        email = input('Insert your Email adress: ')
        while email in emails:
            print('That email is already registered')
            email = input('Insert another Email adress: ')
        password = input('Create a password: ')
        passwordc = input('Confirm your password: ')
        info = [first_name, last_name, email, password]
        while passwordc != password:
            print('The passwords do not match.')
            passwordc = input('Reinsert your password: ')
        for i in info:
            login_data.write(i)
            login_data.write('\n')
    print('Nice! Your account was registered.')
    print('\r')
    register_info()

def login_account():
    register_info()
    with open('Login_Data.txt', 'r'):
        login_email = input('Email: ')
        while login_email not in emails:
            print('Invalid Email')
            login_email = input('Reinsert your Email: ')
        login_password = input('Password: ')
        while login_password != data_text[data_text.index(login_email) + 1]:
            print('Invalid password')
            login_password = input('Reinsert your password: ')
        print('Hello {} {}, welcome back!'.format(data_text[data_text.index(login_email) - 2], data_text[data_text.index(login_email) - 1]))
        print('\r')
user_choice()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `user_choice` is your *main* loop, and so it would be better described as `main`. Whilst fairly undescriptive on what it does you can add a docstring to add information on what it performs.
- It is more idiomatic to use loops in Python rather than recursion. This is partly due to the recursion limit, and partially that the iterator pattern has a lot of support in Python.
- I've rarely seen `'\r'` in Python. I don't see why you would need it and so have just removed them.
- I like the way that you got a users email. The use of a while loop here is pretty clean.
- I would change the prompted text when getting an email as it's different to the rest of the prompts.
- I would DRY your do while loop. There's not really a point to having two different `input` prompts with the above suggestion.
- Recently I was creating an account using `passwd` and multiple times I kept messing up *the first* password entry. It was rather vexing as I knew I messed up and I just had to hope I pressed backspace the correct amount of times to fix my mess up. Unfortunately I wasn't skilled enough to fix my mistake.

  However with your solution I would have to quit out of your entire program, removing the data I have already to fix my mistake. You should instead get again the password and the confirmation.
- There is no point in opening `login_data` until the user input has been confirmed to be correct. You should try to keep `with` statements as small as necessary.
- I would prefer to build a dictionary or an abstract datatype for the user information.
- You can remove one of your `login_data.write`s by passing `i + '\n'`.
- "Login_Data.txt" seems ok, but it's not great. You can use JSON via `import json` and make a much easier and standard file type to work with.
- Your interactions with your globals seem really poor. If you want a global, than I suggest you only have one. This is easy when using dictionaries.

  I would also suggest changing your code to have *no globals*.
- I would change `login_account` to align with the above, changed do-while loops, no globals and using JSON.
- Since we are using JSON we can easily change the format to display the first and last name easier.
- Your solution is in no way safe, it's prone to over the shoulder attacks by not using [`getpass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html) and you're storing passwords in plain-text. This is not safe. Do not use this for anything more than a toy project that will only ever have you entering a password unique to this toy.

```
import json


def main():
    """Create an account or log in."""
    while True:
        print('Hello user, create an account or login to an existing one.')
        choice = input('Insert "1" if you wish to create an account or "2" if you wish to login: ')
        print()
        if choice == '1':
            create_account()
        else:
            login_account()


def input_user_email(emails):
    """Get an unowned email."""
    while True:
        email = input('Email: ')
        if email not in emails:
            return email
        print('That email is already registered.')


def input_user_password():
    """Get a user's email."""
    while True:
        password = input('Password: ')
        confirmation = input('Confirm password: ')
        if password == confirmation:
            return password
        print('The passwords do not match.')


def get_user_information(emails):
    """Get a user's information."""
    return {
        'first_name': input('First Name: '),
        'last_name': input('Last Name: '),
        'email': input_user_email(emails),
        'password': input_user_password(),
    }


def create_account():
    """Create user account."""
    with open('login_data.json', 'w+') as f:
        users = json.load(f)
        emails = {user['email'] for user in users}
        user = get_user_information(emails)
        users.append(user)
        json.dump(users, f)
    print('Nice! Your account was registered.\n')


def login_account():
    """Log into a user account."""
    with open('login_data.json') as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    by_email = {user['email']: user for user in users}

    while True:
        email = input('Email: ')
        if email in by_email:
            user = by_email[email]
            break
        print('Invalid Email')

    while True:
        password = input('Password: ')
        if password == user['password']:
            break
        print('Invalid password')

    print('Hello {0.first_name} {0.last_name}, welcome back!\n'.format(user))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions man, about the '\r' thing, I didn't know how to separate the data in different lines by using '.append'. I'll see if I can learn about encrypting text and JSON, thanks for mentioning that too.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Conversion of a comment to an answer.</sub>

> Definitely avoid the recursion in `user_choice`. It will run out of stack if you keep exercising it for long enough. A simple `while True:` around the rest of the function body should fix it (obviously take out the calls where it calls itself).
>   - [tripleee](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/63322/tripleee)